# Assign Table Name property to generic DBSet<T>

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6

I want to create a table for every registered user and assign the user id to the table name.
i have a model.

```
public class ContactModel
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20), MinLength(6)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(45), MinLength(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Email { get; set; }    
}
```

i want  to create a table for registered users based on this model and use the user id as the table name in the DB.
Thank you.

Comment: Why would you like a table for every user?

Comment: I am trying to create an address book, so i don't to put all contacts in one table for every users of the system, some users can have a very large contact list.

Comment: This is very late but I hope you didn't create a separate table for each user in the end, as @Borka suggested you shouldn't as he was correct. You can partition the table by user on the backend if you need to instead of calving off a new table for each user but it is hard to imagine a user contact list big enough to worry about this. Large db tables are typically very large, like millions of records, not hundreds or even tens of thousands.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i had done it using relational database, I did not have to create a table for every user.